# How to Detect Multiple Image Targets?

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I've got my unity project exported through Vuforia to Eclpse. But, when I run the application only one image target is detected at a time.

In Unity, both datasets have been marked active, but still no use.

I see a lot of links like: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/detecting-and-tracking-multiple-targets-simultaneously

But they only explain how to code away when the app is built from scratch, and not when it is exported through Unity.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've got from my findings.

It's a simple process. When adding the `AR Camera` into the scene you would generally `Load Data Set` and check the one `ImageTarget` `Data Set` needed for that application.

At first I tried simply checking all the `Data Set` I needed, but that didn't work since it helped me detect only one `ImageTarge`t at a time.

Finally, I came across this option within the `Inspector Panel` of the `AR Camera` that called `Max Simlutaneos Detection`. This was it. Enter the value as the number of detections you would need for that applications, and it does exactly that.

Vuforia supports multiple detection upto a certain limit and so this was achieved.